# Dsolve problem with a system of 3 differential equations

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I'm not a mathematician so I apologize if what I'm asking is trivial.
I'm trying to solve a system of three differential equations:
$$
\frac{dA}{d t} = -k_1A(t)+k_{-1}B(t)-nA(t)\frac{dC}{d t}
$$
$$
\frac{dB}{d t} = k_1A(t)-k_{-1}B(t)-(nA(t)-1)\frac{dC}{d t}
$$
$$
\frac{dC}{d t} =k_2B(t)A(t)^{nA(t)}
$$
with the conditions 
$$ 
B(0) = 0
$$
and 
$$ 
C(0) = 0
$$

However, dsolve does not provide an answer - it just runs for a long time. Any help would be appreciated!

Here's the code used in Mathematica:

```
DSolve[{a'[t] == -k1 a[t] + k11 b[t] - n a[t] c'[t], 
  b'[t] == k1 a[t] - k11 b[t] + (n a[t] - 1) c'[t], 
  c'[t] == k2 b[t] a[t]^(n a[t]), b[0] == 0, c[0] == 0},
 {a[t], b[t], c[t]}, t]
```

More information that might be relevant: k1, k11 and k2 are positive and real, typically between 0 and 1. n is between 1 and 4 or so.

And a follow up question - can I use ndsolve to determine the above mentioned parameters, given some c[t] datapoints?

Comment: Please add the code you used in Mathematica. Because a) we're lazy and b) there might be typos

Comment: Here: DSolve[{a'[t] == -k1 a[t] + k11 b[t] - n a[t] c'[t], 
  b'[t] == k1 a[t] - k11 b[t] + (n a[t] - 1) c'[t], 
  c'[t] == k2 b[t] a[t]^(n a[t]), b[0] == 0, c[0] == 0}, {a[t], b[t], 
  c[t]}, t]

Comment: What are the values of `k1` etc.?

Comment: The system is nonlinear, so a closed-form solution may not exist.  Try `NDSolve` to get a numerical solution.

Comment: Why not immediately eliminate C?  $C$ itself doesn't matter to $dA/dt$ and $dB/dt$---only $dC/dt$ does, and you have an expression for that quantity.  I still don't think there will be a closed-form solution (because of $A^A$) but Mma should be able to find a numeric solution.

Comment: Well the trouble is that I can measure C, or I can measure (A+B), which seems less useful. I will try solving numerically without C, results might be useful.

Comment: Note also that the system of ODEs has the first integral, `a[t] + b[t] + c[t] == a[0]`, which also can be used to eliminate one of the three ODEs.

Answer (score 1):

This system can be solved numerically and generally with `ParametricNDSolve`, if you specify an initial condition for `a[0]` (which I picked to be 1 below for concreteness).

```
soln = ParametricNDSolve[{a'[t] == -k1 a[t] + k11 b[t] - n a[t] c'[t],
    b'[t] == k1 a[t] - k11 b[t] + (n a[t] - 1) c'[t], 
    c'[t] == k2 b[t] a[t]^(n a[t]), b[0] == 0, c[0] == 0, 
    a[0] == 1}, {a[t], b[t], c[t]}, {t, 0, 10}, {k1, k11, k2, n}]
```

Now you can play with various values of the coefficients

```
Manipulate[Plot[Evaluate[
   Through[({a[t], b[t], c[t]} /. soln)[k1, k11, k2, n]]], 
   {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All],
   {k1, 0, 1}, {k11, 0, 1}, {k2, 0, 1}, {n, 1, 4}]
```

where I chose the ranges of the parameters based on your suggestion.  This gives a little `Manipulate`d plot:

[image: example manipulate choice]

To get the functions themselves, you can do eg.

```
{AA[t_], BB[t_], CC[t_]} := Evaluate[
    Through[({a[t], b[t], c[t]} /. soln)[k1, k11, k2, n]]]
```

where you plug in concrete numerical values of `k1, k11, k2, n`.  Then you can use `AA, BB, CC` as functions (ie. `A[3]` will produce a numerical value).